# Остается звук, после ухода в сон

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, прочитал гугл, но так и не нашел решения своей проблемы.
В приложение используются hls-трансляции, в качестве плеера выбрал ExoPlayer, так как полной гайдов и есть отличный демонстрационный пример. Все работает отлично.
Но от тестирующего человека поступает жалоба на то, что после выключения экрана звук трансляции продолжается. Поймать этот недочет он смог целеноправленно его ловя один раз в две недели. У меня же вовсе его не получилось поймать.
Сначала я грешил на плеер, но после  долгих попыток исправить это, ничего не изменилось. Возможно что-то надо исправить в самом приложение, что именно не нашел поэтому и задаю вопрос.
ExoPlayer последней версии, устройства на которых поймали недочет: Highscreen Prime Mini и Prestigio MultiPad.
Учасок кода который должен срабатывать при сворачивании:

```
@Override
   public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getContext());
    Map<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Params.put("test echo sound", "OnlinePlayerGragment onPause enableBackgroundAudio = "+enableBackgroundAudio);
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("TestEchoSound ",Params);
    try {//test
        Logi.d("OPF onPause");
        if (!enableBackgroundAudio) {
            audioCapabilitiesReceiver.unregister();
            releasePlayer();
        } else {
            player.setBackgrounded(false);//was true
        }
        shutterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //тест
    }
}

private void releasePlayer() {
    //   Logi.d("releasePlayer");
    try {
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getContext());
        Map<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Params.put("test echo sound", String.valueOf("OnlinePlayerGragment releasyPlayer "+ (player!= null)));
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("TestEchoSound ",Params);
        if (player != null) {
            debugViewHelper.stop();
            debugViewHelper = null;
            playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.release();
            player = null;
            eventLogger.endSession();
            eventLogger = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //тест
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть приложили код как вы пытаетесь остановить воспроизведение при переходе в спящий режим.

Comment: оберните  в отдельный `try...catch` строку `audioCapabilitiesReceiver.unregister();` Если на ней возникнет exception, воспроизведение не остановится.